# Default year view on v-date-picker

Tags: vuetify.js

On v-date-picker, when clicking on the input field I want the date dialog to default to the year view (please see pic below). Which Vuetify's property I can use? Or a code sample that I can add on the mounted() section.[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? :-) SO isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution on the Docs under the "Date pickers - birthday picker" example.
https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers